# React-Native Picker Warning

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am facing a bug when my `ComponentDidMount` function is calling my server to give an array of strings. I use that to setState to keep the strings in the form of an array.

When I used the picker function, I have an strange warning error. After researching, a source said that something was expected as a string but adding a `.toString()` didn't change the warnings.

```
Class test extends Component {
    state = {
        list:[],
        userselected:""
    }
    ComponentDidMount(){
        this.function();
    }
    function = () => {
        Axios.post(url, body, header).then(results =>     this.setState({list:results})...
    }
    <Picker selectedValue={this.state.userselected} onValueChange={(selected) => this.setState({ userselected: selected })}>
          {
               this.state.list.map(item => {
                   return <Picker.item key={item} value={item} label={item} />
               })
           }
    </Picker>
```

Warning message:

[image: See warning message]

Comment: Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I am running into the same thing here and cannot fix it to save my life.

Comment: @JacobBralish i don’t think i ever found the answer to this.

Comment: When this was happening were you also getting errors in your console regarding Picker.item or PickerIOS.item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You and I had the same typo, it is that you are using Picker.item when it should be Picker.Item. Very irritating bug, but should do the job! The same goes for PickerIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the same error when one of my import statements was incorrect, make sure to check them all.

Comment: I remember seeing those issues, but sadly no. This has something to do with Picker Items that i've done.